# Guest Checkout in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, shopping-cart

I am currently developing guest checkout in django as I don't want to use django-oscar which gives guest checkout functionality. I searched and got to the conclusion that it can be done through session and got to know that when user logs in the system at that time row will be created in django_session table. So I will have to create manual entry in django_session for my guest checkout. Can anyone please throw some light on how and which will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way it would be to set `request.session['user']` to some default value (e.g. `guest`) by default (you can do

```
try:
    request.session['user']
except KeyError:
    request.session['user'] = 'guest'
```

at the start of every view function (pr functions that can be accessible directly by typing some URL. That's what I've always done and it makes miracles ;). What it actually does is checks whether a user is logged in (`request.session` has the key `user`) or not (`request.session` does not have the key `user`). When user logs in, set `request.session['user']` to his username.

Comment: By request.session['user'] = 'guest', will it create entry in django_session table?

Comment: No, unless you specifically instruct it to. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to touch the `django_session` table yourself.

Instead, please read

- [a tutorial about the session framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions), or
- [the more in-depth documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/)

The gist of it is that you can store things in the session dict using

```
request.session['foo'] = True
```

and they will be transparently persisted using a cookie. You can retrieve them similarly.